# Tiling in Google Tile Server (x, y and z parameter)

Tags: c#, wcf, google-maps, dictionary, tiles

I am working on Google Tile Server. I have written one WCF Service (C#) which fetches tile from Google server using http URL :-  http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@129&hl=en&x=1&y=0&z=1&s=Galileo

As you know, Google Tile requires three variable parameters x, y and z in it's URL to provide a tile.

Other co-ordinates [can be seen here](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/).

I am very much successful in fetching the Google Tile (Map) one by one (means putting different values of x, y and z).

Now coming to real world scenario, I tried developing one WinForm (C#) application to display those tiles. I am able to display one-one tiles. But my problem is..

1. How to provide complete set of maps (different tiles stitched together)?
   *I know, I can provide multiple calls to Google Tile Server with different parameters but I needed to know what could be the appropriate value of x, y & z in different conditions and continuous relation to that*
2. Is there any calculation, formula or mapping which links screen coordinate to Google Tile Server coordinates (means x, y & z values)?
3. I have to provide smooth zooming and panning on dragging and double click .. same as Google provides.
4. My basic concern is relation between Google's x, y, z and my screen coordinates.

Any help (or samples) will be highly appreciated.

Comment: check http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

The explanation for what you want to do is complicated, and you'd have to figure it out some way, because things don't simply assemble themselves automagically (which is unfortunate in a way).

Even though, I have found the following link literally solved my ignorance problem, so now I can figure things out much easier:

http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

This will explain (with some example formulas) how you can get your desired transformations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Mercator projection to go from Latitude / Longitude to Google Maps tile coordinates (zoom, x, y). See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates for an example. You will first need to convert from Lat / Lon to a "world point" and from there, based on the zoom level, you can convert to a pixel on the entire virtual map image that represents the whole world. Knowing the tile size (256 x 256), you can then convert from pixel to tile coordinates.
Reverse this logic to go from tile coordinates to Latitude / Longitude.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go from lat long to tile coordinates, the bing map tile page gives you all the equations you need. (assuming everyone is using a topleft origin, and 256x256 sized tiles).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

if you need to use different sized tiles, then modify the constants in the equations.